# Login to a website then collect data with Scraping Hub

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

I've used [scrapinghub](http://scrapinghub.com/) for two days and am looking for how to log in into a website then scrape data. I see this topic but can't see how to apply it into the Dash.

http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2012/10/26/filling-login-forms-automatically/

Could you explain me how to achieve that?

When I was just only using Scrapy, I'll achieve it like this:

```
parsed = [FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'session[email]': 'email@gmail.com',
                'session[password]': 'password'
            },
            callback=self.after_login)]
```

But I did not see how to achieve it using Scraping Hub :/

Comment: Hi @Snite, you have a Scrapy spider running fine locally, and you want to deploy it to ScrapingHub's Dash?

Comment: Hello @Paul, I just wan to get the authentication form method with ScrappingHub's Dash. I was running a Scrapy script before discover ScrapingHub's Dash, then this is the last thing I'm not abble to do yet. Because I want autosrapping make the job, and not re-use my scrappy code, or only part of my scrapy code, am I clear ? (If not, don't hesitate to say, I'm French so it is possible that I did not express myself correctly)

Comment: To clarify : I want first to be logging in into my website, then after successfully logging in, run my spider, all of this using ScrapingHub's Dash

Comment: I'm also French (and, disclaimer, I work for ScrapingHub), I've asked the AutoScraping team to check what's possible in Dash for that.

Comment: Thank a lot, I'm lucky :D Waiting for your team's answer, and, by the way, great tool you made !

Comment: Hi @Paul, I would like you to take a look on this topic if not too busy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473629/scrapinghubs-dash-default-value-to-item-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was more simple than expected.

[image: Perform login]

An other problem occur : [on some website, authentication fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491315/perform-login-fail-on-some-website-with-scrapinghubs-dash)