# Perform Login fail on some website with ScrapingHub's Dash

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

When I try to perform login with ScrapingHub's Dash, I get the following error on some web site into the "log" section :

```
scraping hub exceptions.KeyError: 'No input element with the name None'
```

How to fix hit ?

**EDIT :** Here the authentication method :

[image: Perform login]

Comment: ScrapingHub uses [loginform](https://github.com/scrapy/loginform) library to automate the login process. You will have to provide more information about the site you are trying to login so it can be debugged.

Comment: How can I achieve that ? Directly into the form, like : 'login_field_name':'mylogin' and 'password_field_name':'mypassword' ?

Comment: by more information I was referrering to the real "Login Url" field value, something like https://myurl/login is not useful. A better place to ask is http://support.scrapinghub.com/, or if you are a developer able to debug and fix stuff please create an issue with details at [loginform issues](https://github.com/scrapy/loginform/issues)

Comment: https://www.seedrs.com/sign_in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to be a bug in [loginform library](https://github.com/scrapy/loginform), it is fixed by [this change](https://github.com/scrapy/loginform/commit/b5de763147d13bd777afb4460d8b3fa4f0d43279)

and I have tested this in Scrapinghub with success.